# How did Lex Luthor know Bruce Wayne and Clark Kent were important to each other?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In this scene it seems that Lex Luthor knows something that every else does not. That he has brought together a an insignificant reporter with the one of the richest man in Gotham.

What does Lex Luthor know that we don't?

Comment: I think you may be underestimating Clark's significance to Luthor. Mr Kent is Superman's personal biographer and, along with Lois Lane and Jimmy Olsen, someone who can, potentially, put Lex in touch with Superman (or lead him to him) should the need arises.

Comment: This line bothered me too. I see where they were going but he just makes such a big deal about the introduction, its like saying "Bill Gates, how wonderful that you're meeting this reporter that I like...", contextually it seems like he's playing up Clark, or downplaying Bruce, and neither really seem appropriate to me. i think this line falls flat like many others, and is ambiguous enough to just be unnecessary (like several other parts as well, IMHO).

Comment: I thought it was implying that Luthor knew that both men were actually superheros - that he knew who each actually was.  And he was gloating about that like a child with the world's biggest secret.